# Стилизация scrollbar на сайте

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как выглядит наиболее эффективный вариант стилизации скроллбара на сайте? Именно стилизации, а не имитации посредством js. Он должен сохранить все свойства (прокрутка колёсиком, при зажатом колёске, стрелками "вверх-вниз", кнопками home, end и т.д.)

Такое можно наблюдать в различных сервисах google (новое оформление).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google использует возможности браузерного движка webkit, а именно свойство [webkit scrollbar](http://css-tricks.com/9130-custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

И работает оно конечно только в хроме и сафари. А на js есть отличный плагин (правда на jquery) - [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) , который понимает и стрелочки и колесико прокрутки и up/down (только не понимает зажатое колесико, но думаю для большинства людей это не критично).

**offtopic:** Странное решение гугла таким образом демонстрировать преимущества своего хрома, представляю какой бум начнется на стилизированные скроллы, которые естественно должны работать везде а не только в хроме и сафари

Comment: о, спасибо, добавил в закладки.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](http://www.tigir.com/css_scrollbar.htm) подробно описан способ стилизации с помощью CSS, но не уверен, что это обеспечит максимальную кроссбраузерность. Все-таки возможно придется использовать скрипты.

Краткое содержание:

```
scrollbar-base-color:#Цвет; /* Задает основной цвет для скролла */

/* И более тонкие настройки: */

scrollbar-3dlight-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет верхней и левой границ полосы прокрутки, ее бегунка и стрелок*/

scrollbar-arrow-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет стрелок на кнопках полосы прокрутки*/

scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет "тени", отбрасываемой бегунком и кнопками полосы прокрутки (цвет правых и нижних границей)*/

scrollbar-face-color:#Цвет; /*задает основной цвет бегунка и кнопок прокрутки полосы прокрутки*/

scrollbar-highlight-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет "освещенной" части бегунка и кнопок прокрутки полосы прокрутки (цвет левых и верхних их граней)*/

scrollbar-shadow-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет "неосвещенной" части бегунка и кнопок прокрутки полосы прокрутки (цвет правых и нижних их граней). Не путать с цветом "тени", задаваемым атрибутом scroll-darkshadow-color*/

crollbar-track-color:#Цвет; /*задает цвет фона полосы прокрутки, той ее части, по которой перемещается бегунок*/
```

Comment: Это только для ie

Comment: Ну, тогда думаю, что без JS скорее всего никак.